# Syntax error or access violation when inserting a record

Tags: sql, laravel

I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
>   default value for 'id' (SQL: create table `advertising` (`id` bigint
>   unsigned not null default 'None' auto_increment primary key, `slug`
>   varchar(50) collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' not null after `id`,
>   `provider_name` varchar(100) collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' null,
>   `tracking_code_large` text collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' null,
>   `tracking_code_medium` text collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' null,
>   `tracking_code_small` text collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' null, `active`
>   tinyint unsigned null default '1') default character set utf8 collate
>   'utf8_unicode_ci')

and this is my code :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('advertising',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned()->default('None')->nullable($value = false)->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('slug',50)->after('id')->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')->nullable($value = false);
            $table->string('provider_name',100)->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')->default(null)->nullable($value = true);
            $table->text('tracking_code_large')->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')->default(null)->nullable($value = true);
            $table->text('tracking_code_medium')->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')->default(null)->nullable($value = true);
            $table->text('tracking_code_small')->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')->default(null)->nullable($value = true);
            $table->tinyInteger('active')->unsigned()->nullable($value = true)->default(1);
        });
    }
```

I try to change value of id but its still get error.

Comment: `id` is expecting **_integer_** value you are passing **_string_** by default. And auto-increment field doesn't require any default value OR nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a default value for a auto-incremented column, also I don't understand why would you want that to be nullable.

Change this:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned()->default('None')->nullable($value = false)->autoIncrement();
```

To just this:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

`bigIncrements` already means auto incremented and unsigned.